# erlang "erl_nif" functionality

Tags: erlang, ffi

I have interfaced Erlang mainly through port drivers but now with the advent of the `erl_nif` [functionality](http://erldocs.com/R13B03/erts/erl_nif.html), I am wondering if I should invest in Port Drivers anymore.

Will the `erl_nif` functionality boom or bust like `FFI`?

Comment: If you wait you will find out.  Seriously though, this question is pure community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ports and NIFs have different properties and model different types of things: ports behave as processes and you communicate with them through normal message passing, while the NIFs look like normal function calls. So it really depends what you want to interface and how they behave. Both have their place.

Comment: Wouldn't the very same statement be valid for Ports vs. FFI ?

Comment: Yes, it is, but there is a much higher probability that NIF will be supported than FFI. N.B. that NIF is still "experimental" and may still change, though I am reasonably certain that it will become part of the system.